# How does editing other people's questions work?

Tags: support

I edited someone's title and got the message that my edit must be peer reviewed before it will show up. I want to know how that works. (Where should I have looked for this info, if it's not a good question to ask here?)

I am excited about this community, and eager to make it work well. But I have not participated in Stack Exchange communities before.

Comment: This blogpost has some screenshots to give an idea how things will look. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/ Note the design of the site changed slightly so it will not look exactly like this, but very similar.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the original poster of the question has the ability to peer review the edit.  Also, [for the private beta](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), those who have at least 500 reputation will also be able to peer review edits.  For public beta, the number is 1000, and once the site is out of public beta, you'll need 2000 reputation.

Comment: The OP usually doesn't have to review the edit. If just two higher rep users approve or reject then that is it. The OP can, of course, roll back the post to an earlier version.

Comment: So how do higher reputation users find out there's a suggested edit needing a second person's vetting?

Comment: There are small icons displayed on the bar at the top. This will show up when you have sufficient reputation (which no one really does right now).

Comment: You can also see it (though most probably faded out) in the review queues you can access from the top bar if your reputation is higher than 350.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Help Center:

https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Here you can see what reputation is required to be able to do various things. You see, for example, that when you get a reputation of 500, then you can edit questions and answers without any review. It looks like you will be able to review other user's edits when you reach [350 points](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues).